# CMake: how to add compiler flags to non-default compiler

Tags: c++, cross-platform, cmake

Hello I want to build a project with intel compiler.

With default gcc I usually run:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-I/some/path  /path/to/project
```

And this works fine.

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=icpc -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=icc  -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-I/some/path  /path/to/project
```

When I try to use non-default compiler it does not path `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable content to compiler at all.

How to fix this?

**Correct Answer is:**

1. You need to specify the type of the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable:

   ```
   -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING=-I/some/path
   ```
2. You need to provide **full** path to C and C++ compilers:

   ```
   cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/opt/intel/bin/icc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/opt/intel/bin/icpc -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING=-some-flag
   ```

Answer (score 6):

The good way to do what you expect is to use:

```
export CC=icc CXX=icpc cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-I/some/path  /path/to/project
```

Answer (score 3):

Is there some reason that you can't add the include path (from your `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`) to your `CMakeLists.txt` file?

```
add_includes(/some/path)
```

Comment: Yes. I do not want to edit CMakeLists.txt because it is generic file, I just want to add some specifications for specific build. CMake file should not know any kind of local paths of user.

Comment: Your reasoning doesn't make any sense to me. For the build to work for other people, they would also need the files found in that include path. If that's the case, and it's a 3rd-party library that you can't add to the project, then you should have a Find module for it. Putting additional include paths in the CXX_FLAGS variable is the Wrong Way to do it.

Comment: "they would also need the files found in **that** include path." Why do you think so, I point with these flags to some custom-non-standard location of my foo-bar library.

Your assumptions are wrong. Also... CMakeLists.txt is under source control, so I don't want accidentially put irrelevant changes that point to my local files to upcoming tree.

Comment: That's what the Find module is for. You add your custom path to the search list and commit it to the tree. Other developers who have it in a different location will never see a problem. Take a look at the implementations of some existing Find modules - they're in the CMake Modules directory.

Answer (score 2):

I know you don't want to edit the CMakeLists.txt file, but what about editing it allowing the user to select the compiler -- something like

```
SET(MYVAR TRUE CACHE BOOL "Use intel compiler?")
```

And later on, if `MYVAR` variable is set, do the `add_includes()`..? You can also use some package finding utilities (CMAKE provides some) to find the specific compiler include files, etc.